# Is it possible to filter options requests in chrome inspector?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a web application which uses CORS to communicate with it's server.

This means that every request is preceded by one with OPTIONS method.

Is it possible to filter those out in inspector? It makes a lot of unnecessary clutter on network tab.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Yes, you can use `-method:OPTIONS` in the filter of the Network panel to show all methods apart from ones with type `OPTIONS`. If you omit the preceeding `-`, it will only show methods of type `OPTIONS`.

#### Before

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]

**Further Reading**: [Documentation > Chrome DevTools > Network features reference > Filtering](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#filter)

Comment: is it possible to make it by default?

Comment: Just an update, they moved the references to [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter).
And if anyone finds out how to filter both a property and the "name" (path) of requests at the same time, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: @Berbare I know this comes pretty late, but you can just separate multiple search terms with a space: "/api/ -method:OPTIONS" gives you all non-options requests containing /api/.

Comment: We should be able to check / uncheck requests by http-verbs. Similar to how we can check / uncheck XHR / JS / CSS ...

Comment: try `<name> -method:OPTIONS`

Answer (score -3):

Firefox Developer Edition Network Panel shows **OPTIONS** requests without any struggle.
[image: network panel]

Comment: filtering *out*, to be explicit.