# How always to filter OPTIONS Method requests in Chrome inspector?

Tags: google-chrome

I work a lot with Network tab and my application uses CORS to communicate with API, so I see a lot of OPTIONS request that are in most cases useless for me. So I would like to filer them out.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251291/is-it-possible-to-filter-options-requests-in-chrome-inspector) I found solution by using standard build in filter and filter for

`-method:OPTIONS`

[image]

' - ' - means exclude.

But is it possible to make it there **by default**? Not to input this filter each time?

Comment: any findings? this would be so awesome